# Очень долгий запрос mysql count select при наличии трех таблиц

Tags: mysql, оптимизация

Есть 3 таблицы, я делаю запрос по трем таблицам используя `JOIN`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот запрос.

```
SELECT 
  o.name,
  a.creation_date AS a_created_at,
  o.id AS o_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT om.id) AS members
FROM
  `organizations` AS o 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `organization_members` AS om 
    ON o.id = om.organization_id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `activities` AS a 
    ON o.id = a.organization_id 
WHERE 1 
  AND o.deleted = 0 
  AND o.portal_id = 4579009354941859029;
```

Проблема в том что запрос длться очень долго, где то 5 минут.

Индексы поставлены.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как оптимизировать запрос?

Comment: если вам от второй таблицы нужно только число мемберов, то не надо джойнить ее целиком, приджойньте подзапрос, который считаем искомое значение

Comment: Если заменить таблицы на подзапросы? `activities` => `(select id ,organization_id) from activities` и тд

Comment: 1) Вы не указали размеры таблиц. 2) Возможно проблема не в запросе а в настройках(или размере) БД. Приведите `explain` вашего запроса

Comment: Покажите CREATE TABLE всех таблиц, удалив из них неиспользуемые в запросе поля и индексы только с такими полями (но оставьте индексы, в которых используется хотя бы одно поле из запроса).

Comment: Ещё лучше - создайте индекс `organizations (deleted, portal_id, id, name)`.

Comment: @teran спасибо бы мне очень помогли.

Comment: @Akina Вам то же спасибо.